# Is there a way to view file changes in the last week ETC in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I messed something up yesterday in my project, but I don't know what file it was in, and it completely broke it. I want to know if there is an 'extended' file history, or if there is something similar.

Comment: For individual files you can use, `<right click> -> Compare with -> local history`. If you are using version control, other options are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "History" view (Window > Show View > Other... Version Control (Team) > History).

This view will show the local history for each file as you click on it in Project or Package Explorer.

Right click on a revision date / time and choose "Compare Current with Local" to see the difference.